# Script for folder creation

Tags: powershell

Looking for help on a script. Need to be able to import all rows under columns A and B in a csv and then create subfolders in a specific location linking the column names together. Script below is what I have currently and it only creates one folder named"-". Leaving out the source file location and destination on purpose

```
# Define the path to the CSV file and the destination folder where the subfolders will be created
$csvFilePath = "location of CSV"
$destinationFolder = "destination folder"

# Read the CSV file
$csvData = Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath 

# Function to create subfolders based on column A and column B for each row
function Create-Subfolders {
    param (
        [string]$parentPath,
        [object]$data
    )
    
    foreach ($row in $data) {
        $columnAValue = $row.ColumnA
        $columnBValue = $row.ColumnB
        
        # Combine the values from columns A and B to create the subfolder name
        $subfolderName = "$columnAValue-$columnBValue"
        $subfolderPath = Join-Path -Path $parentPath -ChildPath $subfolderName
        
        # Create the subfolder if it doesn't exist
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $subfolderPath -PathType Container)) {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $subfolderPath | Out-Null
            Write-Host "Subfolder '$subfolderName' created successfully."
        } else {
            Write-Host "Subfolder '$subfolderName' already exists."
        }
    }
}

# Call the function to create subfolders for each row
Create-Subfolders -parentPath $destinationFolder -data $csvData
```

Comment: Have you renamed the columns to ColumnA and ColumnB for the sake of this example? As if not, you need to give the actual name of the columns not just A and B, so you may have a CSV with Columns, Name and Address, so it would have to be:

`$columnAValue = $row.Name
$columnBValue = $row.Address`

also rather than passing in [object]$data parameter, I would just have the parameter be the CSV path as a string, and then the function itself would import the csv, as otherwise your just adding an extra step outside the function every time you want to use the function.

Comment: @KG-DROID thank you for that. I am new to scripting and sometimes forget the simple things. I am now receiving a new error for the test path at line 24 char 19 that i need to review

Comment: No worries :), please post the full error here if you need assistance.

Comment: @KG-DROID Here is the error I am getting
Test-Path : Illegal characters in path.
At C:\temp\Create_Folder_CSV_ver4.ps1:24 char:19
+ ...      if (-not (Test-Path -Path $subfolderPath -PathType Container)) {
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Test-Path], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand

Comment: If you write-host  $subfolderPath before that if statement what is it showing as?

Comment: @KG-DROID same illegal character error just further down  Test-Path : Illegal characters in path.
At C:\temp\Create_Folder_CSV_ver4.ps1:24 char:49
+ ... Path if (-not (Test-Path -Path $subfolderPath -PathType Container)) {
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Test-Path], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand

Comment: This error is usually emitted if you try to use characters in a file path that are fundamentally unsupported, such as `"`, `?`, or `<`.

Comment: Glad it helped, @EdB. In the interim, you can try to clean up the names in your code, if it's obvious wha they should be.